# How to rename numerically titled file names by 1 digit?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, mv, for

This feels so simple, and yet I'm entirely stumped. Needless to say I am absolutely new to this. I have a directory with files numerically numbered from `000` to `020`. I would like to rename these files by adding 1 so that `000` becomes `001` etc. Ideally with an `awk` command but any suggestion would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

There are no prefixes, `000` is the whole name. There is no file labeled `021`.

Comment: Thank you, I am using Jupyter and do not have access to zmh or rename, looking for an awk or similar method

Comment: Similar: [how to increase the file extension numerically by one](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/473020) or [Bash - move/rename numeric sorted files from input number onwards](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/558947) or [Rename files by incrementing a number within the filename](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/40523)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `zsh` instead of `bash`, you could do:

```
autoload -Uz
zmv -f -n '*(#qnOn)' '${f//(#m)<->/${(l[3][0])$((MATCH+1))}}'
```

To increase every number in names of the files in the current directory and left-pad them with 0s to a length of 3. So for example `foo-1-2-003.ext` is renamed `foo-002-003-004.ext` or `012` to `013`.

(If the whole file is a number, then `zmv -f -n '<->(#qnOn)' '${(l[3][0])$((MATCH+1))}'` would be enough, or `<0-20>` instead of `<->` to rename only the ones from 0 to 20, or `<0-20>~^[0-9](#c3)` for the ones from 0 to 20 expressed on 3 digits).

The replacement is computed using the `ksh`-style `${var//pattern/replacement}`, with the pattern being `(#m)<->`, `(#m)` to trigger the capture of what's matched in `$MATCH` and `<->` matches any sequence of decimal digits (the bound-less form of `<3-12>`). The `l[width][pad]` left-padding parameter expansion flag is used for padding.

We sort the file list in reverse `n`umeric `O`rder of their `n`ame with the `n` and `On` `q`ualifiers to make sure `file002` is renamed to `file003` before `file001` is renamed to `file002`.

The `-f` disables the sanity checks which here would complain about some destinations being also found in the sources, though that means that it won't prevent data loss if there's both a `file1` and `file01` files for instance.

If you don't have zsh, but have bash and files named 000 to 020 exist and are the ones you want to rename as you later clarified, you can do:

```
for file in {020..000}; do
  printf -v new %03d "$(( 10#$file + 1 ))"
  mv "$file" "$new"
done
```

(bash did copy `{020..000}` from zsh actually, while zsh copied `-v` from bash, that code would work in both shells; the `10#` and quotes are not necessary in `zsh`).

Here, as the file names are very tamed, you can also do things like:

```bash
ls -rq | LC_ALL=C awk '
  /^[0-9]{3}$/ && $0 <= 20 {
    printf "mv %s %03d\n", $0, $0+1
  }' | sh
```

`-q` (standard though not currently supported by busybox `ls`) to make sure there's one filename per line even if there are files with newlines in their name. `LC_ALL=C` so `[0-9]` only matches `0123456789`. If your `awk` is `mawk`, replace `[0-9]{3}` with `[0-9][0-9][0-9]`.

Comment: Thank you your suggestion is not only the solution I needed but clarified so much @Stephane Chazelas

Answer (score 0):

If there are no gaps, e.g. logrotate'd files, then ls can do the work for you, no math / awk needed:

```
dest=021; ls -r|while read file; do mv $file $dest; dest=$file; done
```

and if dest isn't always 021, then something like dest=$(printf "%03d" $(ls|wc -l))

Comment: Would be worth pointing out that that assumes the current working directory contains the 000 001 002 003 004 005 006 007 008 009 010 011 012 013 014 015 016 017 018 019 020 files and no other non-hidden files (and that `$IFS` doesn't contain digits).

Comment: how does $IFS apply to ls output?

Comment: IFS applies to `read` and to unquoted parameter expansions in list contexts. See for instance [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346) and the other Q&As linked from there and [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123). A more correct version would be `ls -r | while IFS= read -r file; do mv -- "$file" "$dest"; dest=$file; done`